# Knockoutjs observablearray Refresh value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I list my status message with knockoutjs Template Binding. My status mesages have like count. I want when ı click my like button refresh my like count where ı clicked it. How can do it. my knockout model code

```html
 var viewModel = {
            messages: ko.observableArray()
        };
        ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
            viewModel.messages(data);
        });
```

and my like button clik code

```html
var LikeButtonClick = function (id) {

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Like", "Home")/' + id).done(function (d) {
                if (d.State) 
                    toastr.info("Beğendiniz.");
                else
                    toastr.error("Beğenmekten Vazgeçtiniz");

                var message = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.messages(), function (currentMessage) {
                    return currentMessage.MessageId == d.Id; 
                });
                if (message) {
                    console.log(message.MessageId)
                    // refresh
                }

            })
        };
```

and my button html code

```html
div class="panel-footer-btn-group  pull-right" style="margin-left:5px; display:block;">
                <button data-bind="click: LikeButtonClick.bind($root,MessageId)" class="btn btn-default like">
                    <span data-bind="text:LikeCount"></span> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an observable property called LikeCount somewhere but you haven't included it in the question.

Somewhere you need to do:

```
var viewModel = {
        messages: ko.observableArray(),
LikeCount: ko.observable();
    };
```

and in your json you need to update that observable:

```
viewModel.LikeCount(data.LikeCount); //or similar
```